# How to override default login redirection route in Sylius

Tags: symfony, sylius

After I login my Sylius app (site login, not admin login), I am redirected to /shop (It is the path to the SyliusShopBundle, defined in my app/config/routing.yml)
Is it possible to override the login redirection to be redirected to / (where I have put static index page)?

Thanks !

EDIT : here is my code after the answer of CoderMaggie

```
sylius_shop_login:
    path: /shop/login
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.security:loginAction
        _sylius:
            template: "@SyliusShop/login.html.twig"
            redirect:
                route: homepage
```

but I am not redirected to route homepage

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you are redirected to the `/shop` it's not the default behaviour. There is no such route even.

But if you are customizing things this will be the approach :)

```
sylius_shop_login:
    path: /login
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.security:loginAction
        _sylius:
            template: "@SyliusShop/login.html.twig"
            redirect:
                route: your_route_here_if_other_than_the_original_one
```

Comment: Tks CoderMaggie. I am redirected to /shop because it is the route I have declared to go to the SyliusBundle. But after login, I would like to go to the root of my website, which is not the shop. I try your solution

Comment: I try adding this code to my app/config/routes.yml, after all the routes for Sylius. But I am still redirected to /shop after my login. Any idea why ? The symfony doc about overriding routes is not very clear : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#routing

Comment: The route seems to be overriden, because if I change loginAction to loginAction2, I have an error. But the redirection to "homepage" does not work.

Comment: CoderMaggie, I was reading the Security doc of Symfony, and saw there is a `default_target_path` in the `firewall.shop.form_login`. I have changed the value from `sylius_shop_homepage` to `homepage` and it worked. Is this a good way to do it ?

Comment: Yes. :D That was the place the the redirect was still present ;)